# Adding background image as a new section to a Bootstrap Site

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Been struggling with trying to add a background image to my Bootstrap site. I am trying to sandwich it between two existing sections.

When inspecting many homepages with background images, they have the class but also the style code in the HTML as well as the CSS.

This is the type of thing I am trying to add, excluding the slider
http://themesquared.com/flathost (div class is jumbotron masthead)
http://themesquared.com/flathost/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/header-bg.jpg

To then some overlay text to the background image, do I need in this order:
Container, Row Class, Background Image Class,Overlay Text Class with col positions

Is both the style needed in CSS and HTML with background images?

```html
<div class="solution5">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-12">
<div class="col-6 push-1"><a href="/link1">
<h1>Link text</h1><h2>2nd text block</h2>
<a href="/link2" class="Link2">Up to 40% off</a>
<a href="/link3" class="Link3">Discover more</a>
<a href="/link4" class="col-3 push-1"><ul class="Link4"><li>Free Bag</li>     <li>Free Delivery</li></ul></a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

```css
.solution5 {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
opacity: 1;
visibility: inherit;
z-index: 20;
background-image: url(http://example.com/img/solution5.jpg);
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
background-size: cover;
background-position: 50% 0%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Comment: create a demo with what you tried sofar?

Comment: No just add `background-image: url('yourimage.jpg');` on section that you want to add background with css

Answer (score 1):

You mean like this :

```css
.solution5 {
  background: url('http://themesquared.com/flathost/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/header-bg.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
}
```

**demo -> http://jsfiddle.net/mmcgaweb/**

regarding `background-size: cover;` from [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) :

> **cover** : A keyword that is the inverse of contain. Scales the image as large as possible and maintains image aspect ratio (image doesn't
>   get squished). The image "covers" the entire width or height of the
>   container. When the image and container have different dimensions, the
>   image is clipped either left/right or top/bottom.